# ¿Cómo encriptar objeto Json usando clave pública PEM?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encriptación

Necesito encriptar un Json usando una clave pública escribí esto pero no me funciona:

```
En esta linea :
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams); 

System.Securyty.CryptographycException Datos Incorrectos
    
        string PUBLICKEY = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA9llGF9C5OZBN1hqKXw8f
        z4kWCJjJqj0UG1sPKwxJyjjXVuwFB8z7kfQZlfSs//mKzyEoO1NNRc+WWROyNwf6
        49fVlcDvcuzyhXtdokajk8Nr7ogoyjWlkAeqmZl4Neurt9wgJMmFyNjkY2RGmhcy
        X8qq59oiOREav4WEUB/3Y+m5a/LAb8b6HNgI+7tNE6ZQvfadWvgPey7J/V0ZvLRn
        ORtm5bA/KWzzJr5jopIgb2xK8QuoyheyMzAUS6EWK4yIH7AzuhBI7UFkKLgvzoW+
        XBzcBwdtqinkPLLnsIIoKVokl9wLpR43Z/mAlzcSitQ4H2qVCZsrE7fnTOBOwlpO
        5QIDAQAB
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        
         public string EncryptObject<T> (T obj)
         {
             var publicKey = PUBLICKEY;
        
             var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (obj);
             byte[] jsonDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
        
             // Calcular el hash SHA256 de los datos JSON
             byte[] hash ;
             using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
             {
                 hash = sha256.ComputeHash(jsonDataBytes);
             }
        
             // Encriptar el hash con RSA y la clave pública proporcionada
             byte[] encryptedHash = EncryptWithRSA(hash, publicKey);
        
             // Devolver la cadena encriptada
             return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedHash);
         }
        
         private  byte[] EncryptWithRSA(byte[] data, string publicKey)
         {
             using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = RSA.Create() as RSACryptoServiceProvider)
             {
                 RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
                 rsaParams.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
                 rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
                 return rsa.Encrypt(data, false);
             }
         }
```

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: En esta linea   rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);   System.Securyty.CryptographycException Datos Incorrectos

Comment: fijate que no te molesten los saltos de linea